# Error with my first spring code

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data, spring-integration

Im Following the first example (starts at 22 page) from the downloaded pdf of the book "learning spring application development".I followed all steps exactly as instructed in the book.
Im getting a red underline at greetUser(), in the below line MainClass.java

```
System.out.println(greetingMessageService.greetUser());
```

GreetingMeessageService.java

```
package org.springframework.chapter1.service;

   public interface GreetingMessageService {

     public String greetUser();

   }
```

GreetingMessageServiceImpl.java

```
package org.springframework.chapter1.service;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
@Service 
public class GreetingMessageServiceImpl  implements  GreetingMessageService 
{

 public String greetUser() {         

return "Welcome to Spring";   
}
}
```

MainClass.java

```
package org.springframework.chapter1.main;

import org.springframework.chapter1.service.GreetingMessageService;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;


public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {          

        ApplicationContext context = new  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");     

        GreetingMessageService greetingMessageService =  context.getBean("greetingMessageServiceImpl",  GreetingMessageService.class);  

        System.out.println(greetingMessageService.greetUser());   
        } 

}
```

beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">


<context:component-scan  base-package="org.springframework.chapter1.service"/>


</beans>
```

Comment: And the error is????

Comment: There is a red Underline under greetUser() in the line System.out.println(greetingMessageService.greetUser()); In MainClass.java. why?

Comment: What is the error. There is a message somewhere... A redline can have thousands of reasons if you don't know the error message it will be hard to help you.

Comment: @Deinum  It magically dissapeared. Thank you

Comment: @Denium I am unable to accept my own answer, kindly some one close it for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

And the red line magically dissappears ?? I spent 2 hrs to get rid of that and all of a sudden its gone.